# Force linebreak OutputLabel

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, line-breaks

I have an outputLabel which contains a lot of text (about 5000 characters of text), the outputLabel has to add a new line after the line is about 200px, is this possible?

```
<p:outputLabel value="#{object.body}" />
<p:outputLabel value="#{object.body}" style="width: 200px" />
```

This code doesn't work:

```
public String getBodyWithLineBreaks(){
    return body.replaceAll("(.{100})", "$1<br/>");
}
```

It is also not a solution because this method does not look if a word is finished, it just starts a new line at the 100th character.

Some more code:

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="object" value="#{notificationOverview.objects}">

     <!--Some more columns...-->  

    <p:rowExpansion>  
        <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="4" style="width:300px;"  
                                                 styleClass=" ui-widget-content grid">  
        <f:facet name="header">Notification Information</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="Sender:"/>
        <h:outputText value="#{object.sender.username}"/>

        <h:outputText value="Time send:"/>
        <h:outputText value="#{object.dateSend}">
            <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"/>
        </h:outputText>

   <h:outputText value="Title:"/>
   <h:outputText value="#{object.title}"/>
</h:panelGrid>

<br/><br/>

<div style='width: 200px;'>
   <h:outputText value="#{object.body}" />
</div>
</p:rowExpansion>
</p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<p:outputLabel>` generates a HTML `<label>` element which is by default an [inline element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elemente). You can't set the dimensions of an inline element. You can only set it on a [block element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements).

One way would be adding `display: block` to the style.

```
<p:outputLabel value="#{object.body}" style="display: block; width: 200px;" />
```

Additionally, given that this is inside a `<p:dataTable>` cell, which has by default its CSS `white-space` property set to `nowrap`, you need to set it back to `normal`. This can be set on the same component, but this is preferably to be set on the parent `<p:column>` itself:

```
<p:column style="white-space: normal;">
```

Note: as part of a good practice, you should prefer `styleClass` over `style`.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the [HTML `<label>` element](http://www.htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/label/) is designed to label an input element which is identified by `for` attribute. I.e. when you click on it, the associated input element retrieves focus (and a checkbox/radiobutton get selected). When validation is performed, the label is used to identify the input element. However, the fact that you're trying to display 5000 characters inside a label element, which is completely user unfriendly when used as a real label, suggests that you're actually abusing the label for the wrong purpose of displaying "plain text". You should be using `<h:outputText>` instead. This generates a HTML `<span>` element which is by default also an inline element. So the above answer applies on that as well:

```
<h:outputText value="#{object.body}" style="display: block; width: 200px;" />
```